# Stations is not a subtype of type

Tags: flutter, dart

For some reason in my flutter app am getting the following error message.

> "type '(Stations) => Stations' is not a subtype of type '(String,
> dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'"

```
Future<Stations?> getStationData(int playerId) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String? token = prefs.getString('jwtToken');
const String path = 'Station/GetFirstPlayerStationTopScore';

final uri = Uri.parse('$url/api/$path');

final Map<String, String> queryParams = {
  'playerId': '25801',
  'type': '11',
};
final Uri uriWithParams = uri.replace(queryParameters: queryParams);

try {
  Response res = await get(uriWithParams, headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  });

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(body);
    if (body != null) {
      return body.map((Stations item) =>
          Stations.fromJson(item as Map<String, Stations>));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    throw Exception('Unable to retrieve posts.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  throw Exception('Unable to retrieve posts.');
}
```

I am calling the above as such

```
HttpService api = HttpService();

void getData() async {
  int playerId = 25801; // Or whatever playerId you want to use
  stations = await api.getStationData(playerId);
}
```

The player exist ok but am not sure what am doing wrong in my model. I was just testing this so not all veriables are filled.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Stations {
  final int? id;
  final int? stationId;
  final String? decimalName1;
  final String? decimalName2;
  final String? playerName;

  final int? decimalValue1;

  Stations(
      {this.id,
      this.stationId,
      this.decimalName1,
      this.decimalValue1,
      this.decimalName2,
      this.playerName});

  factory Stations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Stations(
      decimalValue1: json['decimalValue1'],
      playerName: json['playerName'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'decimalValue1': decimalValue1,
        'playerName': playerName,
      };
}
```

The Error am getting is

```
"type '(Stations) => Stations' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'"
```

I am really new from flutter coming from a c sharp background so bare with me if this is simple stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two mistakes here. First is that it's wrong to write

```
return body.map((Stations item) =>
```

this should just be

```
return body.map((item) =>
```

because the parameter is not already a `Stations`.

But this actually is not the main problem. `map` is used when your object is a list of some sort. But I believe it must be a single `Stations`. I believe

```
  return body.map((Stations item) =>
      Stations.fromJson(item as Map<String, Stations>));
```

needs to be simply replaced with

```
  return Stations.fromJson(body);
```

if this is not the case, please share your response so we can judge what could be going wrong

Comment: its still null later on when am trying to access it form my view when the scafold is called.

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni It would be helpful if you showed us what `body` exacty contains. Try do `print(body);` I feel like you are not working with the response that you expect it to be

Comment: I created a new question as its ui releated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76147673/data-not-displaying-correctly-in-the-scaffold-view @ivo