# Data not displaying correctly in the scaffold view

Tags: flutter, dart

While the previous question got my data in my list ok I am still having issue displaying it on screen.

When I come to inspect the value in the scaffold it is null again bare with me as am learning flutter on a holiday.

```
{stations?.playerName}
```

I am guessing in flutter unlike c# objects dont live beyond there scope how do I get my data appearing in the scaffold section

In my view layer I have the following.

```
HttpService api = HttpService();

void getData() async {
  int playerId = 25801; // Or whatever playerId you want to use
  stations = await api.getStationData(playerId);
}
```

**My View**

The very first text object is trying to display the data.

As you see a declare my data in the build then consume it in the scafold a believe this is where I am going wrong.

```
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     String username;
     String password;
     Stations? stations = Stations();
     final usernameController =
        TextEditingController(text: 'brandon@hockeylabmn.com');
     final passwordController = TextEditingController(text: 'Fitness1!@');

     HttpService api = HttpService();

     void getData() async {
      int playerId = 25801; // Or whatever playerId you want to use
      stations = await api.getStationData(playerId);
     }

     void submitForm() async {
      api.login(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
      getData();
     }

    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              'Welcome:${stations?.playerName}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const Text(
              'Please select a workout type:',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Wrap(
              spacing: 10,
              children: [
                Chip(
                  avatar: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    child: const Text('VJ'),
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Vertical Jump'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Chip(
                  avatar: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    child: const Text('OP'),
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Overhead Press'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Chip(
                  avatar: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    child: const Text('BP'),
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Bench Press'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Chip(
                  avatar: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    child: const Text('PU'),
                  ),
                  label: const Text('PULL UP'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 500.0,
              width: 700.0,
              child: Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                color: Color(0xD3D3D3),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21.0)),
                elevation: 4.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'WorkOutType:',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels
                          Text(
                            'Vertical Jump',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels

                          SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      const Text(
                        'Player Name:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(
                        '${stations?.decimalValue1}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),

                      const Text(
                        'Personal Best',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Row(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Feet:',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels

                          Text(
                            '15',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.orange),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels

                          Text(
                            'Inches:',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              width:
                                  10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels

                          Text(
                            '10',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.orange),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                          width:
                              10), // Add a SizedBox with a width of 10 pixels
                      TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), //<-- SEE HERE

                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                          filled: true,
                          labelText: 'Feet',
                          labelStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), //<-- SEE HERE

                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Inches',
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                          labelStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20, width: 10),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: submitForm,
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, few things i see:

1. You declare your variables and functions (getData and submitForm) inside the build method. This means they get reinitialized every time you call setState. Let's say you have a variable x which gets a value of 3 after you press a button. On the next call of setState it will lose it's value. You should put the function definitions and the variables outside of the build method.
2. I don't see any setState calls or a state management solution to update the ui. Is it missing? I guess this is also a reason why it doesn't update after you get your data.

Comment: You say outside the build method but dont explain where as am new to flutter this is not helpfull.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Flutter, but with basic object-oriented programming. You should set the variables as class attribute and the methods no longer as inner method.

Comment: Actually no that is not the case flutter does things differently in dart ! Than the likes of c sharp or dotnet land and allot of languages

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni you are wrong. This answer is correct. Everything you have above `return Scaffold` needs to be lifted outside the build method. Furthermore you need to call `setState` after you do `stations = await api.getStationData(playerId);`

Comment: Yes but you say lifted out but how on earth do I call it from the scafold then

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni just like that. Not move them out of the class, just out of the `build` method.